# PHP session do not carry after header even with session_start(); on every page

Tags: php, session

I know this problem is very common, and the usual answer is to place `session_start;` at the beginning of every page and script. I've done that and still to no prevail. I've spent literally a whole 6 hours trying to find the mistake, but came to no avail, any pointers would be appreciated.

The relevant codes are below, but just to break it down. There is an **init.php** file that contains all the functions, connections and `session_start();` and this is `include`d into the top of *every* page, *before* any other code.

---

**init.php** (`include`d in **header.php**, *before* any HTML) **[EDITED to include error reporting]**

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require 'database/connect.php'; //code for connecting to database
require 'functions/general.php'; //contains one sanitize function
require 'functions/users.php'; //user-specific functions (see below)

$errors = array();
?>
//rest of the head and opening body tag
```

**index.php** (`session_start();` is at the beginning of the code from **init.php**)

```
<?php include 'includes/overall/header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'assets/nivo/nivo.php'; ?>
<p>plain text
</p>
<?php
echo ($_SESSION['user_id']);
?>

<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
<?php include 'includes/overall/scripts.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**core/functions/users.php** (within **init.php** which contains `session_start();`)

```
<?php
function logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}

function user_exist($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
};
function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
};

function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
};

function login($username, $password) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return  (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
};
?>
```

The login form is `included` into **index.php** and sends data to **login_pro.php**

**login_pro.php**

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a username and password';
    } else if (user_exist($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'User does not exist';
    } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Please activate your account';
    } else {
        $login = login($username, $password);
        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'This username/password combination is incorrect';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
        };
    };

    print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

---

If I place a die function to output `SESSION['user_id'];` into **login_pro.php**, like so:

```
} else {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                die($_SESSION['user_id']);
                header("Location: index.php");
                exit();
            };
```

I ***do*** get the desired user_id. But this is not carried forward after the header redirected me back to index.php - as indicated by the lack of output in the echo function at **index.php**

How do I fix this?

Comment: I am a real novice (learning from phpcademy), so please don't ridicule me if it's something really silly, I promise I've tried and can't find the answer.

Comment: Your extra `session_start()` for safe measure cannot work, because it occurs _after_ output has been sent to the output buffer. Headers (which the session_start() sends) _must_ occur before any output, including whitespace before an opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: You have error reporting _disabled_.  Turn it on, and you might get some valuable insight into what's going wrong here.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` _always_ in development.

Comment: Since you're a novice, I'll point out one other thing - in PHP although it is usually harmless, you do not need, and it is quite unconventional to include a `;` after a closing `}`, as you have after most of your `};`.  JavaScript expects those in some circumstances, PHP almost never does, one exception being an anonymous function declaration into a variable.

Comment: (This is a bit complicated, but...) I can confirm that the init.php file, which is included at the very beginning of head.php, which is included at the very beginning of header.php, which is included in the very beginning of index.php. (So the start_session(); code is placed before anything else - there are no white spaces)

Comment: @Michael Berkowski After enabling error reporting, I get the error:

    Notice: Undefined index: user_id in ***** on line 6

Comment: I thought by including the `start_session();` code at the beginning it would know what $_SESSION['user_id']; is?

Comment: The first time through, `$_SESSION['user_id']` is not yet set, that's why you see that notice.  Do `echo isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : '';` on the echo line instead.

Comment: (thanks again for your help) yep. that got rid of the error, but that means there's nothing in the session id? I am going to use the [best method](http://search.bwh.harvard.edu/concourse/900/articles/SleepInsightWagnerNature04.pdf) I know to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now resolved this problem. It has to do with my hosting provider. I have posted a full explanation to help others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect). If someone deem this question should be deleted, please feel free, I am not very familiar with Stackoverflow traditions.

Comment: Please put the answer to your question here, so that it can be seen alongside the question, and then delete the duplicate question.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but then I realized the actual question is too specific and the code I provided is actually irrelevant.