# Session lost after page redirect

Tags: php, session

I've a problem with PHP sessions.
This is my code:

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
...
...
...
$_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $user['nome'];
$_SESSION['ruolo'] = $user['ruolo'];
$_SESSION['auth'] = true;

header("location: index.php"); 
exit();
...
...
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
...
...
?>
```

result is array(0) { }

I've already seen other similar posts, but no proposed solutions are helpful to me (session_start, exit after header, etc)

Some suggestions?

Comment: U have cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: This link might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect

Comment: Thank for your reply. I've checked everything: as you can see session_start() is in every script; I've tried also with session_write_close() and session_regenerate_id() functions, with no results; cookies was enabled in my browser; register globals is set to off; the Session superglobals is not overwritten anywhere (as you can see from the code). Have you some other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of your script:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".domain.com");
```