# Session variable changing from one page to the other

Tags: php

I have the following code on one page

```
<?php
// Account for the possibility of time out
session_start();
$_SESSION['LoggedIn']=$_GET['LoggedIn'];
$_SESSION['SetName']=$_GET['SetName'];
    $setName=$_SESSION['SetName'];
$_SESSION['UserName']=$_GET['UserName'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) || !$_SESSION['LoggedIn']) header("Location: Home.php");
    php var_dump($_SESSION); 
    header("Location: uploadFiles.php"); // DEBUG
?>
```

If the header("Location: uploadFiles.php"); is commented out, this gives

```
array(3) { ["LoggedIn"]=> string(4) "TRUE" ["SetName"]=> string(4) "test" ["UserName"]=> string(5) "OtagoHarbour" }
```

uploadFiles.php has the following code

```
<?php
// Account for the possibility of time out
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) || !$_SESSION['LoggedIn']) {
    php var_dump($_SESSION);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Not logged in.  Session log in=<?php echo $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] ?>");
    document.location.href="Home.php";
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I get the alert

```
Array(0) {}
Not logged in.  Session log in=
```

Comment: What's the URL by which you call the first page, ergo what's in `$_GET['LoggedIn']`?

Comment: echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" . 
  "document.location.href=\"http://myPage.com/RunGraphicalUploader.php?LoggedIn=TRUE" .
  "&SetName=" . $setName . "&UserName=" . $_SESSION['UserName'] . "\"" .
  "</script>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was remiss in not mentioning that I was using LAMP.  I was also remiss in not checking

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

It had the message

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://whatever.com/uploadFiles.php
```

The following fixed the problem

```
sudo chown www-data /var/lib/php5
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't see the session data in uploadFiles.php as you're not actually printing them out. You need to use `echo` or even better while debugging, `var_dump` as this will highlight null variables. Also your JS syntax is incorrect - the output of the PHP needs to be **inside** the quotes or it will cause a syntax error. Bare in mind that if the session var contains speech-marks, they will need  escaping:

```
<?php
// Account for the possibility of time out
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) || !$_SESSION['LoggedIn']) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Not logged in.  Session log in=<?php var_dump( $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] ); ?>");
    document.location.href="Home.php";
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I made the change, and made the appropriate edit above, but still get the same result.  Thanks,

Comment: OK, can you use `var_dump` to discover what is in `$_GET['LoggedIn']` in your first file?

Comment: It returns string(4)"TRUE"

Comment: Ok, in both files, please do <?php var_dump($_SESSION); ?> and edit your question to include the results (the output is likely to be too long for a comment).

Comment: I edited the question above.  The former file gives array(3) { ["LoggedIn"]=> string(4) "TRUE" ["SetName"]=> string(4) "test" ["UserName"]=> string(5) "OtagoHarbour" } while the latter gives Array(0) {}

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of new ideas, but try this question - it seems pretty closely related to your own problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect