# How can I attach the POST variable values to a new SESSION variable in AJAX and call it from other script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I checked the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect) it but didn't help

I'm trying to make an AJAX Post Request to sumbit my signup form, the **ajax.php** file will check the entered information, example passwords match or not, and then attach the $_POST variable to a $_SESSION variable so that I can call the submitted data from any other page later.

**Ajax.php**

```
...
if ($everythingValid) {
// add this user to db
$_SESSION["signup_details"] = $_POST;
echo "SUCCESS@".$core->signupPaymentUrl($package); // tried without this line but didn't work
exit(); // tried without this line but didn't work
} else {
foreach ($errors as $e) print "<br>".$e;
exit();     
}
...
```

The jquery code that I'm using to call the file is the below:

```
var form = $('#signup');

 $("#submit").click(function() {

$.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'html',
  crossDomain: true,
  url: form.attr( 'action' ),
  data: form.serialize(),
  success: function( response ) {
  if ("SUCCESS" === $.trim(response.split('@')[0])) {
  // user created, redirect to payment page
  var paymentUrl = $.trim(response.split('@')[1]);
  window.location.href = paymentUrl;
  } else {
    $("b#signupErr").hide();
    $("b#signupErr").html(response);
    $("b#signupErr").fadeIn();
    }
  }
} );

});
```

After submitting the form, I successfully get redirected to the payment Url, however, after accessing the page where I want to use my session, I cannot figure out how to retrieve my session although I'm pretty sure that I have included session_start in both of **ajax.php** and **completeOrder.php** and no blank spaces before the opening php tag.

here is the line that I included in both files :

```
if(!session_id())  session_start();
```

I tried to var_dump the $_SESSION variable on ajax.php and It looks okay. However when I var_dump the session variable on completeOrder.php it shows me **NULL**

Finally here is the completeOrder.php content

```
if(!session_id())  session_start();

require_once("core.php");
$core = new coreOptions();
$email = $_SESSION["signup_details"]["email"];
$password = $_SESSION["signup_details"]["password"];
$package = $_SESSION["signup_details"]["pkg"];

$options = $core->attachOptions($package);

if ($core->registerUser($email,$password,$options,$package)) 
$core->redirect("registrationCompleted.php");
```

Comment: How should we know what your `completeOrder.php` file does and how it does look?

Answer (score 0):

in the completeOrder.php file remove `if(!session_id())  session_start();`

and then only add `session_start();` and it will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

[`session_id()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.session-id.php) will return an empty string in `ajax.php` if there was no call to `session_start()` before. So the in `ajax.php` `session_start()` will never be called and the content of `$_SESSION` won't be stored anywhere.

So just use:

```
session_start();
```

in both files.

Comment: I used only session_start on both files but that didn't help.

Comment: Yes but with this if clause. Remove the if clause completely.

Comment: This `session_start();` replaces this `if(!session_id()) session_start();`completely.

Comment: I know that. I did exactly what you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Does `core.php` do anything to sessions?

Comment: Thank you.. I was destroying the session in _construct function. Thank you for help. That was very stupid mistake