# Having trouble passing checkbox value from one page to another in php

Tags: php, checkbox, checked

I could not figure it out what goes wrong. I need to pass the value of my checkbox( if is checked or not checked) , from page1.php to page2.php. Is only just one checkbox, not an array. Mention that either form action I cannot use.

This is the code from page1.php:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $checked = 0;  // not checked
   $_SESSION['first'] = $checked;
   echo "<input value='$checked'  name='name' type='checkbox'> <span class='description'> Enable this?</span>";

 ?>
```

this is the code from page2.php:

```
<?php   

   session_start();
   $checked = $_SESSION['first'];
   if ( $checked == 1  ) {

       echo ' checkbox checked '; 
   }
   else 

       echo ' checkbox not checked ';           

?>
```

Comment: Why you are using while such small value you can pass by parameter

Comment: Did you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect. BTW, how is the page submitted to the back-end?

Comment: Page is submitted by a a submit button. The checkbox is incorporated into a form.

Comment: Where is the submission code?

Answer (score 0):

The original value of $checked:

```
$checked = 0;
```

While:

```
input value='$checked'
```

Result when checked:

```
$_POST['name'] == '0'
```

Then you're incorrectly checking if it equals 1... The value of the checkbox is what gets sent if it is `checked`. Thus you should be checking for '0' to catch when it is selected.

Example:

HTML: `<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" />`

PHP: `if ($_POST['foo'] == 'bar') { // do stuff }`

To then display the checkbox status on subsequent pages instead of setting it's value, you set it's checked status.

HTML5 Specs (same for older):

```
checked = "checked" or "" (empty string) or empty
```

Specifies that the element represents a selected control.

e.g. `<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" checked />`

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html

Answer (score 0):

1 . you should set your form method to post 
2 . set checkbox value in session , as i use in below
3 . if your checkbox click , it will get value 1 which is defined in $checkbox variable , if not check it will get zero
4. if it check and submit the form , then you can set checkbox value in session variable
your page1.php  will have this code

```
<?php  session_start();

if(isset($_POST)) { 
   $_SESSION['first'] = $_POST['name']; // checkbox name
}

   $checked = 1;
   echo "<input value='$checked'  name='name' type='checkbox'> <span class='description'> Enable this?</span>";
?>
```

and your page2.php

```
<?php   session_start();


   $checked = $_SESSION['first'];
   if ( $checked == 1  ) {

       echo ' checkbox checked '; 
   }
   else {
       echo ' checkbox not checked ';           
  }

?>
```

Comment: Noman, that's great. It works excellent. I forgot to store the value on POST for the first page. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would like to be back at my question for some improvement. The solution provided by Noman is perfect, but if I refresh the browser or close and open it again, the information is gone for ever. Is that possible to save the value into a database and how? Any help would be nice.

Comment: yes you can save the values into database , simply write your query under the session save the values from checkbox. right after $_POST['name']; start new line and put it there , do not forget to add your database connection file , or you can put the connection in above (page1.php).. dont forget to vote me up :D