# PHP Centos : Session not able to store

Tags: php, session

Hi Today I am facing one strange Problem 
After login validation I am storing the user name in session and redirecting it to some other page .

Validation page .

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sqlQuery) == 1) {
    session_start();
   $_SESSION['username']  = $login;
   print $_SESSION['username'];
   header("Location: dialout.php");

}
```

.
on dialout.php I am trying to print session like

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

But it doesn't print anything .

some googling I found that problem might be in writing the session directory .

So to check that I wrote one script .

```
print session_save_path();
if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!'; 
    }
else{
 echo "writable -------------";
}
```

From above script I am getting writable.

Just wondering why my I am unable to access the session on dialout.php page

Comment: your qury run fine??

Comment: try this if (mysql_num_rows($sqlQuery) == 1) { echo 'Anything goes'} and what you got as your session depend on your query. if its not working then you are not setting your session. hope it help

Comment: can you try please what i said in the second comment. and let me know what happened. Thanks

Comment: it is printing and    print $_SESSION['username']; also prints value @same page but not work when I try accessing it on dialout page

Comment: are starting session on dialout page ?? you should get value on that page as well if you use session_start(); Thanks and you are starting the session_start(); their and not getting value let me know.

Comment: i dont thing you are starting the session on that page thats why you dont have any value in it. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked php errors ? enable php display_errors directive then show the result. Maybe there is a php error

Answer (score 1):

In your Validation page,the following code should be at the top of the file, as first line in your code.

```
session_start();
```

It should be included in every page if you want to use session variable.

Answer (score 1):

First, carry out these usual checks:

1. Make sure session_start(); is called before any sessions are being
   called. So a safe bet would be to put it at the beginning of your
   page, immediately after the opening
2. After the header redirect, end the current script using exit();
   (Others have also suggested session_write_close(); and
   session_regenerate_id(true), you can try those as well, but I'd use
   exit();)
3. Make sure cookies are enabled in the browser you are using to test
   it on.
4. Ensure register_globals is off, you can check this on the php.ini
   file and also using phpinfo(). Refer to this as to how to
       turn it off.
5. Make sure you didn't delete or empty the session
6. Make sure the key in your $_SESSION superglobal array is not
   overwritten anywhere
7. Make sure you redirect to the same domain. So redirecting from a
   www.yourdomain.com to yourdomain.com doesn't carry the session
   forward.
8. Make sure your file extension is .php (it happens!)

can all be found here: [PHP session lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Call session_start function in dialout.php befor accessing session variable like this :

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```