# keep the login active in season php

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

Hello there i am having a problem i have 2 pages, one its log in and one its private page, when i log in and i try to go to my private page true the link provided, my private page sends me back to log in , like a never ending circle.

- I am fully aware its easy hack.
- if the code looks bad its because i am learning.
- Thank you in advance.
- My log in page

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Login Form - PHP MySQL Ligin System | W3Epic.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>User Login Form - PHP MySQL Ligin System | W3Epic.com</h1>
<?php
session_start("login");
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<!-- The HTML login form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
<?php
} else {
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<table align=center><tr>
        <font color=#000000  face=Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif size=+2>
        <td align=center><p>Logged in successfully</p></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td align=center><p>welcome!</p></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td align=center><p>what wood you like to work whit today ". $username . "!</p></td></tr></table>";

        echo "<table align=center><tr><td align=center><a href=adminsearch.php>
        <class\= color=#000000; face=Arial Black, Gadget, sans-seri;style=”text-decoration:none; size=+2>Admin</a></td>";

        echo "<td align=center>&hArr;</td>";

        echo "<td align=center><a href=constructionsearch.php>
        <class\= color=#000000; face=Arial Black, Gadget, sans-seri;style=”text-decoration:none; size=+2>Construction</a></td>";

        echo "<td align=center>&hArr;</td>";

        echo "<td align=center><a href=drivingsearch.php>
        <class\= color=#000000; face=Arial Black, Gadget, sans-seri;style=”text-decoration:none; size=+2>Driving</a></td>";

        echo "<td align=center>&hArr;</td>";

        echo "<td align=center><a href=industrialsearch.php>
        <class\= color=#000000; face=Arial Black, Gadget, sans-seri;style=”text-decoration:none; size=+2>Industrial</a></td></font></table>";

}
}
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my private page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == true) {
    echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
} else {
     header ("Location: login.php");
}

?>
<?php 
//load database connection
require_once("db_search.php");
if (!isset($_POST['submit']));
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
// Search from MySQL database table




$search=$_POST['search'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from admin where psc LIKE '%$search%' OR trade LIKE '%$search%'  LIMIT 0 , 10");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
// Display search result
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> How To Create A Database Search With MySQL & PHP Script | Tutorial.World.Edu </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="search" placeholder=" Search here ... "/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
  if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
    echo "Search found :<br/>";
    echo "<table style=\"font-family:arial;color:#333333;\">";  
    echo "<tr>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">First Name</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Last Name</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Trade</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Post Code</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Telephone</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Comments</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">To be use</td></tr>";            
   while ($results = $query->fetch()) {

    echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";            
    echo $results['f_name'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";           
    echo $results['l_name'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";           
    echo $results['trade'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";           
    echo $results['psc'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
    echo $results['phone'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
    echo $results['comm'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
    echo("<button onclick=\"location.href='del.php?del=" . $results['id'] . "'\"> delete user</button>"); 

    echo "</td></tr>";              
     }
    echo "</table>";        
     } else {
    echo 'Nothing found';
     }
?>
```

Comment: `session_start` needs to be called at the *top* of *every* page. Also, I've never seen it called with a parameter, and I can't find any documentation...

Comment: before output, not top: **To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP session lost after redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never actually call `session_start();` in your private page, nor do you ever set `$_SESSION['login']` in your login page.

**Login page**

```
if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
```

**Private page**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == true) {
```

Comment: Thank you MR Daniel 6/h of trying to understand it and fix it

Comment: how do i do that can you p[lease let me know thank you