# PHP session variables lost after redirect

Tags: php, session-variables

Session variables are lost after using the following code to redirect:

```
    header('Location: ./protected_page.php');
    exit; //doesn't seem to do anything
```

On protected page I make sure to use **session_start()** before referencing any session variables.

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP session lost after redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect)

Comment: `session_start();` will be the first line after starting`<?php` tag on top of each of your pages.

Comment: still doesn't work despite that

Comment: Post your complete code, from and to redirection pages, both.

Comment: After a bit of debugging, the variables are reset immediately after using session_name($session_name). any ideas? There is a lot of code mixed with HTML, can I post all of that here?

Answer (score 0):

- You redirect to the same domain.If you are redirecting from 
  www.thedomain.com to thedomain.com can possibly end you session
- Ensure register_globals is off, you can check this on the php.ini file and also         using phpinfo().
- The session variables aren't overwritten.
- switching between http and https can also end your session.

Comment: After a bit of debugging, the variables are reset immediately after using session_name($session_name). Not sure why. Once that line is commented everything seems to work fine.