# Codeigniter url changes from 'localhost' to 'http://127.0.0.1/'

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562910/4713946

This is my problem, and I am not sure about the answer. I am unsure where I put this code. I cannot comment on the post itself as I do not have enough reputation so I have to start a new thread. /:

Can someone maybe help me out.

I do a redirect() and when I do this, the 'Localhost' changes to '127.0.0.1'

Comment: I ended up getting it fixed :) check answer below. . . but thank you :)

Comment: Just read comment in config file above the line.

Answer (score 5):

So turns out all I had to do was change 'base_url' in 'config.php' file:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = '/';
```

Comment: I would not have just the / slash in base_url

Answer (score 3):

You should set your base url if your using codeigniter 3 versions

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

If base url is blank it codeigniter 3 versions will show ip_address in url instead of localhost.

Comment: is this the same as '/' or is there a specific reason to do it this way? because so far '/' is working ok. will it cause trouble later?

Comment: I'm unaware just having / of it causing issues but I have been told it's better to have a base_url like above.

Comment: When I do it this way, It does not work because it ends up: 'http://localhost/yourproject/surveys/index'

maybe it is the way I have MAMP set up? EIther way, both answers are good to have on here, I am assuming it depends on how it is set up, but maybe I am wrong. All I know is it did not work for me.

Comment: If you want to get to the index function of surveys  just type in `http://localhost/yourproject/surveys/'` make sure you class and file name have first letter upper case  Example: `Surveys.php` and `class Surveys extends CI_Controller {}`

Comment: You may have to use url with index.php example: `http://localhost/yourproject/index.php/surveys/` if you have not removed it with a htaccess and on your config file.