# PHP Session variables not readable on debian azure server

Tags: php, apache, azure, debian

I have got a problem with my php sessions. I have created a debian server on Azure and installed a php/MySQL/apache on it.

The code I use is functional, because it works on my production server but impossible to read `$_SESSION` variables on this new server.

I can see files well written in `/var/lib/php5/sessions`, and this directory is readable for the apache user.

In a same page, the `$_SESSION` variables are available, but not after a redirection on another page.

Is anybody has an idea ? in apache2.conf ? php.ini? network configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

As the production PHP runtime, the session is disabled by default, you can check the PHP configurations via `phpinfo()` function for the setting of `session.auto_start`. Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start for more info.

You can set the `session.auto_start` to `1` in `php.ini` to enable the session automatically.

Otherwise, you can add the code `session_start();` in the begin of your PHP script to enable session manually.

Comment: Thanks for your  answer Gary. Actually, on my production server, session.auto_start is OFF (0) but I use session_start(); in my code. And it's the same on my dev environment. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Could you please check the issues in this answer of http://stackoverflow.com/a/17242347/4989668