# Can retrieve session after php redirect (with exit()) on localhost but not on Godaddy Server

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I hosted my website on Godaddy. I encountered by the past the problem of retrieving my session after a php redirection by using exit() as following:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['mysession']='session_name';
header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/?blabla=blubb');
exit();
```

Ant it works great but when I export my code on Godaddy server, it doesn't work out there, I can't retrieve my session anymore, and I don't know why.
Please help me.

Comment: Do you have a `session_start();` before you're trying to set or get the session? If you don't, you might have `session.auto_start` enabled on the previous server while it's disabled on GoDaddy's server. (Disabled is the default)

Comment: Yes I do have session_start()

Comment: This actually looks like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect (there are many Q/A here on SO about the same thing, you should check them out).

Comment: Indeed, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17242346

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `session_start();` should be included at the beginning of the php page.

If you have html code in your page, Then it should be look like this:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

$_SESSION['mysession']='session_name';
header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/?blabla=blubb');
exit();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work, I got this error "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/..."

Comment: `<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
?>` Just try this.!

Comment: @EdgarKAMDEM if you get someone to solve something for you, then mark it answered with the green check mark. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 . You also have the rep to upvote posts (the up arrow). I am trying to answer a mysql question for you, but you have no history of doing what I just said