# PHP Session Gets Lost After Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, session, redirect

I have a wordpress website hosted at wordpress.org. And also an independent `PHP` application deployed on the same location (sharing the same hosting).

The independent application has its own login page and home page. When a user logins, I set a session flag indicating user has logged in. However, when I redirect to user home page (after login), all the values from `$_SESSION` are lost.

Cookie path is set to the '/' and `session.save_path` is set to '/var/lib/php5'

I have checked the answer given in [PHP session lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect) and verified all points.

Also, I have followed the steps mentioned here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-_session-info-gets-lost-from-an-external-login-page-to-a-wp-installation

But none of these are working.

Can anyone suggest what could be the possible issue and resolution for it? Thanks.

PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19

Comment: Does the path writable by your server? The usual path for session is '/tmp/', I think.

Comment: Cross site sessions Hmmmm I hope not. Are these 2 different domains?

Comment: Have you checked if your browser's cookies have changed? I know you have checked if it is enabled, but have you checked if the browser received new cookies or kept the same old cookies?

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is deployed on same domain and the redirect occurs on the same domain as well (from http :// abc.com/s/login.php to http :// abc.com/s/main.php)

Comment: @frz3993 I tried setting the session_save_path to a different physical directory as well but it didn't help.

Comment: @PEMapModder It kept the same cookie. I checked the `PHPSESSID` and it retained the value

Comment: Did you make sure you didn't empty the value yourself? What about trying to do session_start and printing the session value at the very beginning of the triggered script (rather than other included files, if any)?

Comment: Check your session save path. Does the session file gets created there?

Comment: @PEMapModder No I didn't. I just set the session and redirected and first thing I'm doing on the next page is to check the session again.

Comment: @frz3993 I just checked the session save path (the one that I overriden in my code just before session_start() there isn't any file there. The path told by phpinfo is out of my bounds as it is a shared hosting service. I can only check my home directory via FTP and hosting panel.

Comment: Then, why not create the session directory in your home directory?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't comment out or amend wp_unregister_globals. Checkout http://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/ for examples of how to achieve sessions in Wordpress without messing with wp_unregister_globals.

I use this and it works a treat:

```
    add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
    function myStartSession() {
        if(!session_id()) {
            session_start();
        }
    }
```

I would also consider storing your session data in the database rather than in files, particularly as you are in a shared server environment. Anyone else on that server could potentially access your sites session data and take over a users session.

In my most recent plugin I created a new table in the Wordpress database to store session data, then use set_session_save_handler to change the behaviour. So my start session script became something like this:

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
    function myStartSession() {
        if(!session_id()) {
session_set_save_handler('open_session', 'close_session', 'read_session', 'write_session', 'destroy_session', 'clean_session');
        session_start();
        }
    }

add_action( 'session_gc', 'session_gc'); 

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'session_gc' ) )
{
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'session_gc' );
}

function open_session()
{
    return true;
}

function close_session()
{
    return true;
}

function read_session($sessionid)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $session_table_name = $wpdb -> prefix . "sessions";

    $query = $wpdb->prepare(
                        "SELECT data FROM $session_table_name
                        WHERE id = %s",
                        $sessionid);

    $result = $wpdb -> get_var($query);

    if ($result)
    {
        return $result;
    } else
    {
        return '';
    }
}

function write_session($sessionid,$data)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $session_table_name = $wpdb -> prefix . "sessions";

    $rowsaffected = $wpdb->replace(
                            $session_table_name,
                            array(
                                    'id' => $sessionid,
                                    'data' => $data
                            ),
                            array(
                                    '%s',
                                    '%s'
                            ));

    return true;
}

function destroy_session($sessionid)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $session_table_name = $wpdb -> prefix . "sessions";

    $rowsaffected = $wpdb->delete($session_table_name,array('id' => $sessionid),array('%s'));

    $_SESSION = array();

    return true;
}

function clean_session($expire)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $session_table_name = $wpdb -> prefix . "sessions";

    $wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare(
                "DELETE FROM $session_table_name
                WHERE DATE_ADD(last_accessed, INTERVAL %d SECOND) < NOW()",
                $expire
        )
    );

    return true;
}

function session_gc() {
    global $wpdb;

    $session_table_name = $wpdb -> prefix . "sessions";

    $query = "DELETE FROM $session_table_name WHERE last_accessed < date_sub(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
    $wpdb->query($query);

}
```

See http://www.stormyfrog.com/using-wpdb-outside-wordpress/ for tips on accessing the $wpdb class from outside Wordpress. You could simply include wp-load.php, then I think you would get the session behaviour for free as I'm pretty sure the init hook comes in after wp-load.php, the downside to that of course is you put the overhead of loading Wordpress into your own pages which you may not want.