# Session is not working in different page

Tags: php, session

I create a `session` and try to access it from another page under same domain and directory but it is not working.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $_SESSION['abc'] = 'ajsdkla skjld ajsdlkja skld jasl';

   echo $_SESSION['abc'];

      ?>
```

Code for second page

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  session_start();
  echo '<h1> Session = '.$_SESSION['abc'].'</h1>';
    ?>
```

You can also check it on live here is a page one [link](http://projects.imube.com/quiz/tutorial/biology.php)
And here is a second page [link](http://projects.imube.com/quiz/tutorial/video.php)

When I try to access `session` on second page I found this error `Notice: Undefined index: abc`

I really wonder why this is happing can you please check it.

Comment: put `ini_set('display_errors', true)` on top and you will see what's the problem

Comment: you probably start the second page with a new line before the `<?php` tag, remove that

Comment: Add `header("Location: video.php");` at the end of "biology.php" to see if `$_SESSION` is recognized when executed immediately.

Comment: I don't receive any session data, more likely the headers are already send. Check @Federkuns comments

Comment: Same error. Both are not solving problem. can you please check it live on clicking links

Comment: this is working fine in localhost but not in this server

Comment: This might help = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your live server (imube.com) responds with

```
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=c1eb78a09f6cfe7830d6d445f95fa748; path=/; domain=.sadishop.com
```

That's a php configuration problem, since the cookie's domain don't match. You can change that in runtime with `session_set_cookie_params`, example:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.imube.com');
```

or you can change the `session.cookie_domain` parameter in your php.ini configuration file and leaves it empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
use the following code
```

biology.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $_SESSION['abc'] = 'ajsdkla skjld ajsdlkja skld jasl';
   echo $_SESSION['abc'];
   header('Location: video.php');
?>
```

video.php

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  session_start();
  echo '<h1> Session = '.$_SESSION['abc'].'</h1>';
?>
```

Comment: _use the following code_ - why? explain what you changed and why this should works.

Answer (score 0):

**Include some code in .htaccess file **

```
RewriteEngine On
php_flag output_buffering on
```