# $_SESSION doesn't keep the ldap $link_identifier

Tags: php, session, ldap

I encountered a strange behaviour of the session variable when storing the ldap link identifier to it. For that I have created two php snippets.

**test1.php:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test']=ldap_connect('ldap://asc-OpenLDAP.asc.asc-syscon.de');
  echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

Output: *Resource id #2*

So far everything is nice and fine.
But then when I try to use $_SESSION on the second page it suddenly holds a wrong value.

**test1.php:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test']=ldap_connect('ldap://asc-OpenLDAP.asc.asc-syscon.de');
  header('Location:test2.php');
?>
```

**test2.php:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

Output: *0*

Why is that so? How can I make it keep the correct value from test1.php?

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP session lost after redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store `Resource` in storage, because session data is serialized before save. Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: First of all thanks for the fast help. Second: Indeed! Thats the problem. But is there a workaround to carry over the 'ldap link' Ressource to another page?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because all resources are destroyed at script execution end.