# Create php $_SESSION from count variable

Tags: php

I am trying to create a $_SESSION from example code count($result). I have decalred the variable like thus:

```
$result = array();
$result[] = $boxdest;
```

This is working fine on the page where I run it but I need to pass the value to a page to use in php mail() function. I have tried

```
$_SESSION['result'] = $result;
```

But all I get is Resource id #40. How do I pass this variable to another page. Full code example here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba0a34774e30c93edfdf02f531bb199c681021e3 Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_SESSION doesn't keep the ldap $link\_identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388191/session-doesnt-keep-the-ldap-link-identifier)

Comment: What's `$boxdest` ?

Comment: @ponury How is that a possible duplicate?

Comment: @aporkryfos it is part of foreach loop

Comment: @user1532468 is it a number?

Comment: @apokryfos yes it is

Comment: From your exact description I can't reproduce an issue (e.g. create `$result =[]` append a number to it, store it in the session and retrieve it in another page). Can you provide some more details of the code? Ideally something that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @apokryfos Can you supply code you used in your example because I am not sure what you need to see. thanks

Comment: @user1532468 check http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e111205911de4ab50c2b33c4e63c2a239e0e92f , I had to merge the 2 pages I had into one just to outline what I did and also sessions won't work in the sandbox but that code (split into 2 files) works as expected

Comment: @apokryfos I have put code at: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba0a34774e30c93edfdf02f531bb199c681021e3 Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 you should include it in the question though.

Comment: @apokryfos I have included link in original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a critique of the code rather than a solution to the problem:

```
$_SESSION['result'] = []; //Clear it in case there's an old value here.
if (isset($_POST['boxdest']) && is_array($_POST['boxdest']) && !empty($_POST['boxdest'])) { //Merged condition
    $destroydata = explode(',', $_POST['boxdest'][0]); //Split was deprecated
    $result = array_filter($destroydata);
    if (empty($result) { 
           $boxdesterror = '<span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;color: #ff0000;">' . 'BOX DESTRUCTION ERROR! ' . '</span>' . '<span style="font-weight:normal;color: #000;background-color:#ffa;">' . 'You must enter a box for destruction' . '</span>';
           echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
           echo 'alert("BOX DESTRUCTION ERROR:\nYou must enter a box for destruction.");';
           echo "</script>";
           echo $boxdesterror;
    } else {
        echo 'You wish to destroy ' . count($result) . ' box(es): ' . '<div style="word-wrap:break-word;white-space: pre-wrap;overflow:auto !important;height: 100px; width: 250px; border: 1px solid #666; background-color: #fff; padding: 4px;">' . '<span style="font-weight:bold;color: #000;">' . implode(', ', $boxdest) . '</span>' . '</div>' . '<p />';

        $_SESSION['result'] = $result; //Did you really need both?
        $flag = 1;
     }
}
```

This should be the same results. I don't see why a resource would pop up from nowhere though.

Comment: Thanks for that. What is the best way to count items in an array and create session from same. more like a size option

Comment: You could do `$_SESSION["resultSize"] = count($result)` and use the resultSize entry instead if you just want the size.

Comment: This is the output from var_dump which dosen't seem right does it?: 'result' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'DEMO10051B' (length=10)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'DEMO10051B' (length=10)
          1 => string 'DEMO10052A' (length=10)

Comment: That doesn't look right. I would have expected result to be an array of strings using this code. Are you sure there's nothing else going on in the 2nd page which may alter the result?

Answer (score 0):

U can't store any `Resource` in PHP session

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42389037/5361130

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

**EDIT**

if your `$result` is result of function like `mysqli_query` or something like this, use `mysqli_num_rows` to get number of rows not `count`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

```
$result = mysqli_num_rows($boxdest)
```

or

```
$_SESSION['result'] = mysqli_num_rows($boxdest)
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is count the number of items in an array and creat session from result.