# Session variable not stored on other pages

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am using session variable to send details of user from login page to welcome page .

here is my  code :

```
<?php   

 if(isset($_POST['login']))
 {



 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $pass=md5($_POST['password']);


 $a="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'AND password='$pass'";
 $log=mysqli_query($con,$a);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($log);


if(mysqli_num_rows($log)>0){

 $_SESSION['firstname']=$row['first_name'];
$_SESSION['lastname']=$row['last_name'];


header("location:welcome.php");
exit;
}
else{

$er="login failed!";

 }
}
```

on Welcome.php

```
 <h2>WELCOME : <?php echo $_SESSION['firstname'];?></h2>  <--- line 63-->
```

but i am getting this error :

> Notice: Undefined index: firstname in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\welcome.php on line 63

PS : kindly dont mark it as duplicate I tried many solutions but not helping. I used session_start(); on every page .

Comment: Have you tried to put session_start() at the top in both files at the same time?

Comment: Check what session array prints on welcome.php page. print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: no, I included the session_start(); in header.php and included it on all pages .

Comment: Array ( [username] => basiclearner [session] => mc7dvh7u6n232dc23ipb6l4bok )     this is i am getting with  print_r($_SESSION) on welcome .php   basiclearner is the name i used but it keeps giving me the same name everywhere .

Comment: I suggest you to check the session after setting firstname and lastname and before redirection.

Comment: i echoed all the $_SESSION values giving perfect result on same page before redirecting to welcome.php .

Comment: @basiclearner In your session variables the index was `username`, not `firstname`.

Comment: it was old session variable no variable is showing now . only session id

Comment: I hope this post will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect

Comment: Really md5 password hashing in 2017? i advice you to read this http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php.. you also might want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php to prevent SQL injections

Comment: i am in early stages of learning it is the basic thats why i am using md5 .

Answer (score 1):

A session is started with the session_start() function.

in 1st page:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($log)>0){


    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($log);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['firstname']=$row['first_name'];
    $_SESSION['lastname']=$row['last_name'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['firstname']))  
        header("location:welcome.php");
    exit;
}
```

on page 2:you might have write this line at 1st line:

```
<?PHP 
  session_start();
 ?>
 <h2>WELCOME : <?php if(isset($_SESSION['firstname']))  {echo $_SESSION['firstname'];}?></h2>
```

Comment: OP sais:  `I used session_start(); on every page .`

Comment: I used session_start(); on everypage .

Comment: @basiclearner also, please make sure that in your welcome.php page, there is no space or anything before the `<?php session_start(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** this answer is not correct and I will remove it when the comment-discussion has ended.

You fetch the first row of `$log` and then AFTER that check if the number of rows in `$log` is bigger than 0. Although you had one row initially, you fetched it! so at the time you check `mysqli_num_rows($log)` it will be 0, **therefore never setting `$_SESSION['firstname']` and  `$_SESSION['lastname']`**.

Try checking for number-of-entries *before* fetching the row like this:

```
$a="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'AND password='$pass'";
$log=mysqli_query($con,$a);

if(mysqli_num_rows($log)>0){


    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($log);

    $_SESSION['firstname']=$row['first_name'];
    $_SESSION['lastname']=$row['last_name'];


    header("location:welcome.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: If that is the case, redirection should also not work.

Comment: @basiclearner can you var_dump the `$row` and give us the result?