# I can't store data to session when with redirect

Tags: php, session

I can't store data to session storage when I redirect to user, how can I fix this ? if add a view instead redirect, it works.. but below codes doesn't work..

```
public function makeLogin(){
        $model = new User();
        $user = $model->read()->where("username","=",post("username"))->first();
        if(password_verify(post("password"),$user['password'])){
            $_SESSION['auth']['user'] = $user['name'];
            $_SESSION['auth']['username'] = $user['username'];
            $_SESSION['auth']['user_role'] = $user['user_role'];
            return redirect('redirect-core');
        } else {
            session("message","wrong username or password");
            session("message_type","danger");
            return redirect(ref_url());
        }
    }
```

`session()` helper

```
function session($name = null,$message=null){
   if (is_null($name) && is_null($message)){
       return new \Core\Session();
   } else {
       $_SESSION[$name] = $message;
   }
}
```

`redirect()` helper

```
function redirect($url){
     if (substr($url,0,4)==="http"){
         header("Location:".$url,true,303);
     } else {
         header("Location:".APP_URL."/".$url);
     }
}
```

Comment: did you `session_start()`?

Comment: @delboy1978uk yes, of course

Comment: what is this session function in the else? that's not a standard PHP function. why do it differently?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I edited my question. I manage standart session messages with this method

Comment: can you show, your code in redirect() helper

Comment: @GautamRai I edited my question

Comment: It might help: [PHP session lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242347/9764507)

Comment: not this one but below answer works, thank you :)