# Lost session after header

Tags: php, session

Yes, I know that a similar question has already been asked> 1000 times, and yet I ran into a problem when the session disappears after calling `header ();`. I read many solutions, but none of them helped (for example: [PHP session lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect)) I make a simple basket, which after clicking Buy, enters the item id into the session and loads the page again. I tried a huge number of options, but none of them helped.
All files are in UTF-8 encoding.
I do not use `echo`.
`session_start ();` at the beginning of the php file.

**index.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
//ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//echo "path: ".ini_get('session.cookie_path');
//include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test_cart/includes/magicquotes.inc.php';
$items = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'desc' => 'Item 1', 'price' => 24.95),
    array('id' => '2', 'desc' => 'Item 2', 'price' => 1000),
    array('id' => '3', 'desc' => 'Goldfish (2 CD)', 'price' => 19.99),
    array('id' => '14', 'desc' => 'JavaScript (SitePoint)', 'price' => 39.95));


if (!isset($_SESSI0N['cart'])) {
    //echo "Init Cart";
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Buy') {
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_POST['id']);
header('Location: .');
die();
exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Claer') {
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);

    session_regenerate_id(true);
    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['cart'])) {
    session_start();
    $cart = array();
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id) {
        foreach ($items as $product) {
            if ($product['id'] == $id) {
                $cart[] = $product;
                $total += $product['price'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    include 'cart.html.php';
    exit();
}


include 'catalog.html.php';
```

**catalog.html.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
function html($text) {
    return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

function htmlout($text) {
    echo html($text);
} ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html  lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Catalog</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            td, th {
                border:1px solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Cart:<?php
            echo count($_SESSION['cart']); ?> items.</p>    
        <p><a href="?cart">View Cart</a></p>
        <table border="l">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Info</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php htmlout ($item['desc']); ?></td>
                    <td>
                        $<?php echo number_format($item['price'], 2); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php htmlout($item['id']); ?>">
                                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Buy">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;  ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**cart.html.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
//ob_start();
function html($text) {
    return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

function htmlout($text) {
    echo html($text);
} ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cart</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td, th {
            border:1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Cart</h1>
    <?php if (count($cart) >0): ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Info</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td>$<?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($cart as $item): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php htmlout ($item['desc']); ?></td>
                    <td>
                        $<?php echo number_format($item['price'], 2); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p>Cart empty!</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form action="?" method="post">
        <p>
            <a href="?">Continue shopping</a> 
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Empty cart">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least a typo here ($_SESSI0N instead of $_SESSION):

```
// if (!isset($_SESSI0N['cart'])) { should be
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    //echo "Init Cart";
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
```

Actually your cart key is reset to empty array at each `index.php` call.