# $_SESSION message gets unset after header() is sent

Tags: php, session

**SOLVED** | **UPDATE:** *As it was not that easy to find a solution, I post the answer below. Hopefully this will help others to find the solution easier on the stackoverflow.*

I've got my own functions to set and show messages. Those messages are stored in session. What I want to achieve is to show a message just once after a form is submitted. And it works unless I use header() function to reload the page or redirect to another page.

I use `ob_start()` and `session_start()` on the top of my header. So these two are there all the time.

My message is set up by the function below. It creates a message of success or danger type and store it in a session variable.

```
protected function setMsg($text, $type) {
        if($type == 1) {
            $_SESSION["message"] = '<div class="alert green"><p>'.$text.'</p></div>';
        } elseif($type == 0) {
            $_SESSION["message"] = '<div class="alert red"><p>'.$text.'</p></div>';
        }
    }
```

The other function shows message just once and after that it is unset.

```
public function showMsg() {
        if(isset($_SESSION["message"]) && !empty($_SESSION["message"])) {
            echo $_SESSION["message"];
            unset($_SESSION["message"]);
        }
    }
```

And here is the final piece of my form submission code:

```
$this->setMsg("User has been created", 1);
header("Location: users_list.php");
```

If I don't use the `header()` function, then it's alright. But I must use it.

The message function is called out in the header, but below all the other functions:

```
<?php $data->showMsg(); ?>
```

So, it seems that page gets redirected twice somehow. After the first time the message gets unset, and after the second refresh I just can't see it. So I can't see it at all.

What more likely I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please always search for solution before posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured it out. In this particular case I just need to insert `exit()` right after calling `header()` function. And that's it.