# when I send value from a page to another page using session, the following error appears

Tags: php, session

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56/sess_c84fdb91458e26c7325faf74a529a3,
>   O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in
>   /home/username/public_html/test2.php on line 3
>
> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path:
>   /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56) in
>   /home/username/public_html//test2.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: username in
>   /home/username/public_html/test2.php on line 4

i used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380712/session-in-php-works-only-on-the-same-page-but-does-not-work-on-other-pages-in/55381145#55381145) but add

```
(error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);)
```

to above of **test2.php**

Comment: Could you please add more details (including your code) to help answer the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your session directory `/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56/` on sever may be not exist or you do not have permissons to access to it.

Create directory if not exist with proper permissions or change session directory in php.ini file.  If you dont have access to server contact your service provider.

You can set below line before accesing or creating sesssion to change session directory for your script.

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/path/to/your/folder')
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Comment: Thank you for your help, I created the directory /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56/ with permission, it works fine.