# Php check password and password confirmation

Tags: php, forms

I'm making a sort of instagram and therefor I need a register page. I want to check of the password is equal or longer than 8 characters and if password and passwordconfirmation are the samen.

I've tried making a new class Security or a try - catch.

register.php

```
if ( !empty($_POST)) {

    $user = new User();
        $user->setFullname($_POST['fullname']);
        $user->setUsername($_POST['username']);        
        $user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
        $user->setPassword($_POST['password']);
        $user->setPasswordConfirmation($_POST['password_confirmation']);

        if( $user->passwordsAreSecure()) {
                if($user->register()) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $user->getEmail();
                    header('location: index.php');
                } else {
                    $error = true;  
                }
        } else {
            $error2 = true;
        }
    }
```

My user class

```
public function passwordIsStrongEnough(){
                if( strlen( $this->password ) <= 8 ){
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
        }
        public function passwordsAreEqual(){
                if( $this->password == $this->passwordConfirmation ){
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
        }

        public function passwordsAreSecure(){
                if( $this->passwordIsStrongEnough() 
                    && $this->passwordsAreEqual() ){
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
        }
```

function register

```
public function register() {

                $password = Security::hash($this->password);

                try {
                    $conn = Db::getInstance();
                    $statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (fullname, username, email, password) values (:fullname, :username, :email, :password)');
                    $statement->bindParam(':fullname', $this->fullname);
                    $statement->bindParam(':username', $this->username);
                    $statement->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
                    $statement->bindParam(':password', $password);  
                    $result = $statement->execute();
                    return($result);

                } catch ( Throwable $t ) {
                    return false;

                }

        }
```

I want to get to the `if( $user->passwordsAreSecure()) {` so there is a session but now the form fields go empty and nothing happens.

Comment: might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect

Comment: oh okay, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur to understand where is you problem. You haven't ask any question... But you can do all your code just like this :

```php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $user = new User();
    $user->setFullname($_POST['fullname']);
    $user->setUsername($_POST['username']);        
    $user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
    $user->setPassword($_POST['password']);
    $user->setPasswordConfirmation($_POST['password_confirmation']);

    if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password_confirmation'] 
            && strlen($_POST['password']) > 8) {
        if ($user->register()) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $user->getEmail();
            header('location: index.php');
        } else {
            $error = true;  
        }
    } else {
        $error2 = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! The problem is that when i try to register and press on submit it stays on the page register and does not go to index.php. So there is no session and the data doesn't go in my database!

Comment: @CesarPeeters can we see your register(); function ?