# session cookie set SameSite=None; Secure;

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, header

the server is running PHP Version 5.4.45
Google Chrome will limit Cross-Site Tracking by default beginning February 4, 2020. 
Which will cause problems for a Procurement Application that connections to our website via an iframe

I need to set the session cookie with SameSite=None; Secure;

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You could google for "how to set the session cookie with SameSite=None; Secure".

Answer (score 6):

`SameSite` is available from *php version* `>= 7.3`, in [php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-samesite) and in [session_set_cookie_params()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) if used in the form `session_set_cookie_params(array $options): bool`

About *php version* `< 7.3`... <strike>I honestly don't know if using`header()`would override the options set by `session_start()`. it could, maybe I'll try and update the answer.</strike>

I did a simple test with `php:5.6-cli` (docker image, I think it was 5.6.40) and it seems to work as expected:

```php
session_start();
header('Set-Cookie: ' . session_name() . '=' . session_id() . '; SameSite=None; Secure');
```

By default this version of php set the session cookie only with `key=value; path=/`, using `header()` is overwritten, only one cookie is sent in the response, and only with `SameSite=none; Secure` (verified in Chromium cookies, and wireshark packets)

However, I would recommend testing with the version of php you are using, the behavior may change.

<strike>Personally I am thinking of not using `session_start()`, storing sessions in a db and using normal cookies set with `header()`.</strike>

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php
 session_name() must be called before session_start() for the session to work properly.

Comment: @VsevolodAzovsky probably when you pass a name to set, not when you read it (this code I had tried it and I had no problems)

Comment: I believe path=/ needs to be set in the Set-Cookie header, otherwise multiple session cookies will be set for each folder accessed.

Answer (score 0):

For end-of-life versions of PHP like this, primarily you should upgrade as you are already exposing yourself to a number of known security vulnerabilities.

However, to patch this, you will need to update the places where you may be using `setcookie()` to manually set the header, e.g.

```php
header('Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=bar; SameSite=None; Secure');
```