# This PDO login form also logs me when I enter a wrong password. How to fix that?

Tags: php, session

I am am trying to improve my login system for my students. I don't really understand this stuff.

I am using this from [here](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/12214/login-and-register-using-pdo-php.html):

It works on my laptop, but ...

I registered a user: mymail@somewhere.com, PW: Monday0518

I registered, logged in, no problem.

Then I deliberately entered a wrong PW. I still got in! I did not save the PW.

How can I alter this to take me back to the login page when the PW is wrong??

```
<?php
    //start PHP session
    session_start();

    //check if login form is submitted
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        //assign variables to post values
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //include our database connection
        include 'conn.php';

        //get the user with email
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM peter_users WHERE email = :email');

        try{
            $stmt->execute(['email' => $email]);

            //check if email exist
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                //get the row
                $user = $stmt->fetch();

                //validate inputted password with $user password
                if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
                    //action after a successful login
                    //for now just message a successful login
                    $_SESSION['success'] = 'User verification successful';
                }
                else{
                    //return the values to the user
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

                    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Incorrect password';

                }

            }
            else{
                //return the values to the user
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

                $_SESSION['error'] = 'No account associated with the email';
            }

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Fill up login form first';
    }

    header('location: ../Neil_Exam/NEleitfile.html');
?>
```

EDIT: I tried this:

```
else{
                    //return the values to the user
                    //$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    //$_SESSION['password'] = $password;

                    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Incorrect password';
                    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'makePassword/index.php');
                }
```

and this:

```
else{
                //return the values to the user
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

                $_SESSION['error'] = 'No account associated with the email';
                header('location: login.php');
            }
```

Even when I enter a wrong email and password, I still get to the page:

> header('location: ../Neil_Exam/NEleitfile.html');

Something is wrong!

I think I need to unset the session on wrong PW or email!

I realized that there is no logout.php Maybe I need that??

EDIT AGAIN: This seems to work, but I have no idea if it is the correct way to do this! Maybe you experts can advise me?

```
//validate inputted password with $user password
                if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
                    //action after a successful login
                    //for now just message a successful login
                    $_SESSION['success'] = 'User verification successful';
                    header('location: ../Neil_Exam/NEleitfile.html');
                    exit();
```

Without exit(); I just see the login form and the message "User verification correct'

I would still like a logout button somewhere, or automatic logout. I suppose that is for another question

Comment: `header('location:` somewhere else.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect, specifically the parts about `header()`, and exiting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
else{
     //return the values to the user
     //$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     //$_SESSION['password'] = $password;

     //no need to set session of user enters incorrect password, just redirect the user to login page

     $_SESSION['error'] = 'Incorrect password';

     //redirect to the login page here

}
```

you should redirect the user to the login page if the password is incorrect