# $_SESSION variables are not working on second page

Tags: php

I have created a session at my first page:

```
<?php 
  $youtubeID = get_sub_field('youtube_id'); 
  $withlastSlash = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $withoutSlash =  substr_replace($withlastSlash, "", -1);
  $howtoURL = $withoutSlash . "?a=" . $youtubeID;
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['howtovidsurl'] = $howtoURL;
?>
```

I have then called the session variables in my second page

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    echo $_SESSION['howtovidsurl']; 
?>
```

But nothing is getting echoed out on the second page.

Comment: First try to print the session variable on same page to check it has no errors and printing something

Comment: @VirenderKumar I have tried this and it is printing the correct string.

Comment: check if session is working in other application if not then try for other xampp installation or try to run this code on your live server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP session lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect)