# Session is missing after redirect

Tags: php, session, centos

I'd like to store the session when I redirect to another PHP file using javascript's `window.location`. But somehow, the session is always missing on the server while it's fine on my localhost. The server is still using an IP Address like this: http://1.1.1.1/app/check_session.php. The server is using CentOS. What I used here as the root path is the `/app`, is it cause the problem?

---

UPDATE:

- `session_id()` changed after redirect to `check_session_submit.php` [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQxzk.png) > [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfWcP.png), even refresh the `check_session.php` it keeps changing

---

Here's my code:

check_session.php

```
<?php

session_start();
echo "Session Path: ".session_save_path()."<br>";
echo "Session ID: ".session_id()."<br>";

$_SESSION["test"] = "test";
?>

<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function delayer(){
            window.location = "check_session_submit.php";
            exit();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["field_1"])){
    $_SESSION["field_1"] = $_POST["field_1"];
    ?>
    <body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 1)">
    <?php
}

?>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="field_1">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

check_session_submit.php

```
<?php

session_start();
echo "Session Path: ".session_save_path()."<br>";
echo "Session ID: ".session_id()."<br>";
echo "Session Data: ".json_encode($_SESSION);

?>
```

I have followed the instructions given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242347/9858781 but still no luck. Tried to save the session into the specified path as mentioned in that comment `.../app/cgi-bin/tmp` and add the permission to directories by using `chmod 777`, but still, the session is not saved. I tried to check the Apache error log from `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and there's no error reported. Is there anything else that I can look into?

Here's my server session configuration:

```
session.save_path = "/tmp"
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.serialize_handler = PHP
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.sid_length = 26
session.trans_sid_tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form="
session.sid_bits_per_character = 5
```

These are the HTTP headers from the server response:
[server response HTTP header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCHzy.png)

Comment: Session handling is largely defined by the various [session configuration settings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) so in order to investigate this question, you will need to post those details.  It would also be helpful to supply the HTTP headers that the server responds with (particularly any `Cookie` headers).  Without this information, it will be very hard for anyone to answer this question.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I added the session configs above and the screenshot of server response HTTP header, is there something that I can fix?

Comment: the order of your code is problematic. Your `<body>` tag might appear AFTER your `<form>` and `<script>` tags, and the `<html>` and `<head>` are completely missing. You have to rewrite the whole script.

Comment: I updated the `check_session.php` code above, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Your cookie header have secure flags which said that your session id is valid only for https. How thats happen ?

Comment: I tried to add `ini_set("session.cookie_secure", 0);` and `ini_set("session.cookie_httponly", 1);` within the file, but the result still the same

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved when I use domain with https, however if anyone can have other solution when it's still on server IP address, please write the answer below, thank you!